# Change scale to logarithmic for Spectrum Analyzer in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, frequency, logarithm

The title says it all. I have a graph showing in linear. I checked on Mathworks and it says you can only show in log (View >> Spectrum Settings >> Trace Options >> Scale) only if the spectrum doesn't contain negative values.

So, I changed the span to start from Zero. But that didn't help as well.

**How can I change the scale to log?**

Comment: I'd suspect that 0 is also an illegal value.  What happens if the span is strictly positive?

Answer (score 0):

The spectrum of frequencies should contain strictly positive frequencies. In this way it works for me, I am allowed to change the scale to logarithmic.

I am using MATLAB r2015b.